# Wix CMS - Dynamic Title for Store Collections

Tags: velo

I am using WIX store and have the below question:
I need to add a text content [BigTitle 1] available only when i choose **Collection/Category**

- Dryvenner

.
When i choose another Category/Collection [ex: **oppfinnelser**], Big Title 1 should change to Big Title 2; so what i need is to create dynamic text content linked to each category, any advise?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit light on the details, but I'll try to point you in some directions, and hopefully it will help.

Looks like you are on a Stores product page and you want to know what collections the current item belongs to. To do so, you can use the [`getProduct()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/productpage/getproduct) function to get the ID of the current product. Then, you can query the [`Stores/Products`](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-wix-stores-products-collection-fields) database collection to get the stores collections that the item belongs to.

From there, you can use the `$w()` API to hide/show or change the text of headings you want to show.